# Assigning in R programming Loop

Tags: r, loops, dynamic, assign

I need to replace this code and Dynamically assign rep(NA, n) for each attribute and value. How can I do it ? I tried below code but doesn't work. Please help.

This is the code need to be replaced -

```
Attribute_1_Value = Attribute_1_Name = Attribute_2_Value = Attribute_2_Name = Attribute_3_Value = Attribute_3_Name = rep(NA,n)
```

This is the code I tried but didn't work. It gives me error "value for ‘Attribute_1_Name’ not found "

```
for(i in 1:3) 
  { 
    tempName <- str_replace("Attribute_%d_Name", "%d", i)  
    tempName = rep(NA,n)

    tempValue <- str_replace("Attribute_%d_Name", "%d", i)  
    tempValue = rep(NA,n)
  }
```

Comment: I don't think this is a very clear question.  Can you provide what the data looks like currently and and what you'd like it to look like?

Comment: In addition to clearing up the question, what is `n` ?

Comment: n is a integer variable. You can consider is as 5. - Thanks.

Comment: All I'm asking is rather than writing Attribute_1_Value = Attribute_1_Name = ........... n number of times I need to automate it. How can I do it ?

Comment: `i <- 1:5; paste0('Attribute_', i, '_Value = Attribute_', i, '_Name', collapse = ' = ')`

Comment: Very Close. This gives me : Attribute_1_Value = Attribute_1_Name = Attribute_2_Value = Attribute_2_Name = Attribute_3_Value = Attribute_3_Name = Attribute_4_Value = Attribute_4_Name = Attribute_5_Value = Attribute_5_Name But I'm looking for .................. Attribute_1_Value = Attribute_1_Name = Attribute_2_Value = Attribute_2_Name = Attribute_3_Value = Attribute_3_Name = Attribute_4_Value = Attribute_4_Name = Attribute_5_Value = Attribute_5_Name = rep(NA,n)

Comment: Also.. I'm not exactly asking to paste, rather trying to assign values dynamically.. something like this ....   How can I do it ?                                   Attribute_1_Value = Attribute_1_Name =  rep(NA,n)
  Attribute_2_Value = Attribute_2_Name = rep(NA,n)
  Attribute_3_Value = Attribute_3_Name = rep(NA,n)

Comment: This is the Answer of my question. I could able to fix the solution.

Comment: for(i in 1:length(dnvParameterVector)) 
  { 
    nam1 <- paste("Attribute_", i, "_Name", sep = "")
    assign(nam1, attributeNames[i])
    print(nam1)
  }
  
  for(i in 1:length(dnvParameterVector)) 
  { 
    nam2 <- paste("Attribute_", i, "_Value", sep = "")
    assign(nam2, rep(attributeFilter[i],n))
    print(nam2)
  }